# How to check if the given username in the register page exists in some of the two tables

Tags: php, html, mysql, registration

I want to check if the given username exists in at least one of the two given tables and if it is exists then it will shows them a message that the username already exists. I wrote some code using the UNION statement but it does not show me the message. Can you tell me please what is wrong with my code?
Thanks

```
if (mysql_num_rows(queryMysql("SELECT * FROM doctor
                  WHERE username='$username' UNION SELECT * FROM patient
                  WHERE username='$username'")))
                $error = "That username already exists<br /><br />";
            else
              {
                queryMysql("INSERT INTO doctor (fname,lname,username,email,password,gender,age,specialty,doctorID) VALUES('$fname','$lname','$username','$email', '$password','$DoctorG','$DoctorAge','$specialty','$Doctor_ID')");
                die("<h4>Account created</h4>Please Log in.<br /><br />");
              }
```

Comment: `if(mysql_num_rows($the_query_result) > 0)` ??

Comment: @AvinashBabu can you explain more briefly your comment please

Comment: Can you tell where this code runs, I'd like to use the SQL injection vulnerability to hack it.  I'm just kidding about the wanting to hack it, but you've left it open for people to do some nasty things to your site.  search for SQL injection.

Comment: you need to check if the username is contained in he mysql table as rows right ??

Comment: @Daniel it is a personal project it is not online , they cant hack it and if they do i have a back up

Comment: @AvinashBabu i want to check if the username exists in one of the two table of my database

Comment: @niklakis "Hacking" isn't just about destroying things. It is that they can use your resources (computer, network, etc...) to do "Bad Things".  I hold my personal projects to a pretty high standard.

Comment: @niklakis have you already tried my answer?

Comment: @SuperDJ I am trying right now , i will inform you as soon as possible for the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
function exists( $detail, $table, $column, $value ) {
    $stmt = mysql_query("SELECT `$detail` FROM `$table` WHERE `$column` = '$value'");

    if( mysql_num_rows($stmt) >= 1 ) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

if( exists('username', 'doctor', 'username', $username) === false && exists('username', 'patient', 'username', $username) === false ) {
    echo 'user doesn\'t exists';
} else {
    echo 'user exists';
}
```

You should really consider using `mysqli_*` or `PDO` instead of `mysql_*` since it is depracted and will be removed